# how to create or write a file in android on phonegap?

Tags: javascript, cordova, phonegap

I am using below code to write a file on android using PhoneGap, I think that this line `window.requestFileSystem(LocalFileSystem.PERSISTENT, 0, function (fs) {` is giving the error,  can't find the exact error, just because I can't debug on android. 
I find PhoneGap documentation confusing.

```
function download_file(cur_filename)
{
    alert(5);
    window.requestFileSystem(LocalFileSystem.PERSISTENT, 0, function (fs) {
alert(2);
console.log('file system open: ' + fs.name);
alert(3);
fs.root.getFile(cur_filename, { create: true, exclusive: false }, function (fileEntry) {

    alert("fileEntry is file?" + fileEntry.isFile.toString());
    // fileEntry.name == 'someFile.txt'
    fileEntry.name==cur_filename;
    // fileEntry.fullPath == '/someFile.txt'
    writeFile(fileEntry, null);

}, onErrorCreateFile);

}, onErrorLoadFs);
}

function writeFile(fileEntry, dataObj) {
    aler(4);
    // Create a FileWriter object for our FileEntry (log.txt).
    fileEntry.createWriter(function (fileWriter) {

        fileWriter.onwriteend = function() {
            console.log("Successful file write...");
            readFile(fileEntry);
        };

        fileWriter.onerror = function (e) {
            console.log("Failed file write: " + e.toString());
        };

        // If data object is not passed in,
        // create a new Blob instead.
        if (!dataObj) {
            dataObj = new Blob(['some file data'], { type: 'text/plain' });
        }

        fileWriter.write(dataObj);
    });
}
```

Comment: if you have an error, for sure, the error callback function will have information about it. Please also share the error code/message received in the error callback.

Comment: `Uncaught ReferenceError: LocalFileSystem is not defined
    at ondeviceready (<anonymous>:92:30)`

Comment: did you install the file plugin?

Comment: I also tried the 'deviceready' event, because I found that maybe the plugins didn't get ready,

Comment: yes, I check, the file and file transfer plugin are already there in PhoneGap

Comment: because this is not a plugin error. The place where you are trying to access, the plugin instance is not available. if you are doing the logic on app launch, then for sure it should be called inside `deviceready`

Comment: can you please suggest what is the proper way to do this.

Comment: what exactly are you after mate?

Comment: I want to download the file from esp which can easily be downloaded in the browser (by calling `http://192.168.43.54/text.csv`) and didn't download in android, so I took the approach in which I create the file and write on it in android platform.

Comment: You can use the file transfer plugin to directly download this. Not write the file. Its a direct application of file plugin download functionality

Comment: I think the basic issue is that no plugins are working

Comment: when I use filetransfer then it is giving me this error `Uncaught ReferenceError: FileTransfer is not defined
    at download_file (<anonymous>:85:24)
    at HTMLHeadingElement.onclick ((index):1)`

Comment: Give me some time, ill send you a sample snippet

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, you can directly download the file rather than having to create and write a new one. You need to first install the following plugins

```
cordova plugin add cordova-plugin-file
cordova plugin add cordova-plugin-file-transfer
```

Now, you need to enclose the below logic inside `deviceready` event in case you are accessing plugins on app launch. The `file-transfer` ships with a `download()` that you need to use for downloading your file. Please find a sample code below

```
document.addEventListener("deviceready", startDownload, false);

function startDownload() {
  var fileTransfer = new FileTransfer();
  // replace uri with -> http://192.168.43.54/text.csv
  var uri = encodeURI("https://file-examples.com/wp-content/uploads/2017/04/file_example_MP4_1920_18MG.mp4");

  fileTransfer.download(
    uri,
    cordova.file.dataDirectory + 'videos/big_buck_bunny_720p_1mb.mp4',
    function(entry) {
      console.log("download complete: ", entry);
    },
    function(error) {
      console.log("download error source " + error.source);
      console.log("download error target " + error.target);
      console.log("download error code" + error.code);
    }
  );
}
```

Once the download is completed, the `entry` object will have a `nativeURL` property that holds the local URL to the file.

**More info**

[File Plugin](https://github.com/apache/cordova-plugin-file)

[File-Transfer Download](https://github.com/apache/cordova-plugin-file-transfer#download)

Comment: bro if I am using 'deviceready' event then 'startdownload' function is not executing.

Comment: as i said, if you are calling this logic after app launch, you need to call `startDownload()` directly.

Comment: if I am using it without deviceready then it is giving me filetransfer is not defined

Comment: like, are you using any framework like angular? or plain JS?

Comment: I am using simple javascript in Phonegap

Comment: when do you call the function? after app launch?

Comment: yes, after app launch and at perticular navigation button